# I want to Change the highlight td when value of td changes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am doing one small project on Stock Market. Here i need to change the **highlight** the **td**  as soon as the data changes and if data increased then green highlight and if data decrease then red highlight.

> In Snippet you must not able to see the result because you need to
>   allow_url_open=0.

Please help me how to do so... :)

```js
  function loadlink() {
    $('#stockdata').load('http://techsoul.in.md-in-1.webhostbox.net/hostedsite/demo/mockup/stockapi/stockshow.php?api=Y', function() {
      $(this).unwrap();
    });
  }

loadlink(); // This will run on page load
setInterval(function() {
  loadlink() // this will run after every 5 seconds
}, 5000);

$("td").change(function() {
  $(this).effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
});
```

```html
<body>
  <div style="margin:0 auto; width:500px;" id="stockdata">Loading...</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a functional example from which you might be able to get some ideas:

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/4sfko6pc/)</kbd>

```js
var o1=0,o2=0,o3=0;
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function updateTable(){
    //Next 3 lines just get the latest stock market values
    var t1 = getRandomInt(10,99);
 var t2 = getRandomInt(10,99);
 var t3 = getRandomInt(10,99);

    //Compare to previous values (O = Old)
    var u1 = (t1 < o1) ? 'lightpink' : 'palegreen';
    var u2 = (t2 < o2) ? 'lightpink' : 'palegreen';
    var u3 = (t3 < o3) ? 'lightpink' : 'palegreen';

    //Update table with new values
    $('#td1').text(t1);
    $('#td2').text(t2);
    $('#td3').text(t3);

    //Colorize rows
    $('#tr1').css({'background-color': u1});
    $('#tr2').css({'background-color': u2});
    $('#tr3').css({'background-color': u3});

    //Save current values as OLD values (for next time comparision)
    o1 = t1; o2 = t2; o3 = t3; 

    //Delay 1.5 seconds and re-run
    setTimeout(function(){
        updateTable();
    },1500);

}

updateTable();
```

```css
table{border-collapse:collapse;}
td{width:50px;border:1px solid #ddd;padding:5px 10px;text-align:center;}
tr{background:#ddd;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr id="tr1"><td>One:</td><td id="td1" class="tdval">Microsoft</td></tr>
<tr id="tr2"><td>Two:</td><td id="td2" class="tdval">Exxon</td></tr>
<tr id="tr3"><td>Three:</td><td id="td3" class="tdval">Apple</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The link you have provided loads a table with **id=bcontent**. You can use javascript or jquery to get the no. of tr/tds in the table and store them in a variable and then you can easily detect if no. of rows have increased or decreased and act accordingly.

With Jquery,

```
$('#bcontent tr').length;
```

With javascript,

```
document.getElementById("bcontent ").rows.length;
```